# What is the name of the fuctionality that makes some options appear after long pressing an app logo on ios home page?

Tags: ios

[image: Demonstration of a home screen quick action menu]

I have tried to find the official name of this functionality however could not.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/home-screen-actions/

Answer (score 1):

> ##### Home Screen Quick Actions
>
> Home screen quick actions are a convenient way to perform useful, app-specific actions right from the Home screen. People can get a menu of available quick actions when they touch and hold an app icon (on a 3D Touch device, people can press briefly on the icon to see the menu).

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/home-screen-actions/